# XSLT for removing tags not working for a XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
<Details>
<date>Posted: 08/22/2011 </date>
<title>Hi this is Jake. I am Smart</title>
<text></text>
</Details>
</article>
```

I have the following XLST to remove the Details and /Details  tag

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Details"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
```

Output expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>

<date>Posted: 08/22/2011 </date>
<title>Hi this is Jake. I am Smart</title>
<text></text>

</article>
```

I tried this. But it is not removing the 
"Details" and "/Details" tag.

Comment: Given your details, your transformation produces the wanted output indeed. Therefore you may showing a too simplified version of your input XML or you may using a buggy XSLT processor.

Comment: @_aniket69: You seem to be confused. The solution you provide, which happens to be mine, *is* producing the wanted result. You either: 1. Are using different source XML document, most probably with a default namespace; 2. Are using code that is different from the one provided; 3. Are using a non-compliant/buggy XSLT processor; or 4. Any combination of 1 - 3.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<xsl:template match="Details"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
```

will *remove* `<Details>` itself, but it will also process *its contents*. Use

```
<xsl:template match="Details" />
```

to remove it entirely (tag and contents).

(If `<Details>` still appears in *your* output, then your question is not complete.)

Comment: Thanks. I want to remove just the tags and not its contents. Just the <Details> and  </Details> should be removed from the XML

Comment: @aniket69: That is *exactly* what your sample XSL stylesheet already does.